# Is Google Analytics API More Up-to-date than GA site during the same day?

Tags: google-analytics

I've got an API query that pulls Acquisition/Channel data by day, users, sessions, bounce rate, etc.  Historically, I tie out exactly to the data shown at the GA site.

I've built a new report that analyzes our same-day sales, and find that all my numbers are much higher than that shown on the GA site.  This was the situation yesterday, and now my data, pulled this morning, ties out.

I haven't seen the GA site update our numbers in hours, but my GA API data is changing on each pull.

Is this expected behavior?  Have others seen similar things?

Comment: Yes its 1 day behind .

Answer (score 0):

Data going into GA and pulled from the API is not real-time. There is a [processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency) with data processing that could be 24-28 hours.